# Will the Entity Framework 4 work with MVC 2 - since MVC is based on 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Can I use the upcoming Entity Framework 4 with aspnet mvc 2 since mvc is based on 3.5?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2.0 is part of .NET 4 and VS2010 - I don't see any problem using it together with EF 4

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2 is *not* part of .NET 4, though it *is* bundled with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4):

If you target .NET 4.0 with your ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Project...you shouldn't have any issues using the new version of Entity Framework.

...or at least I haven't had any issues as of yet.

Comment: MVC 2 is build on 3.5, so wouldnt you have to use 3.5?

Comment: Nope, you don't have to. All versions of ASP.NET MVC are compatible with both .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can always create a separate project that will contain the reference to EF4 and then just reference that project from your MVC project. Depending on your architecture, it might be a good idea to separate these concerns anyways.

Also remember, the new versions of the .NET framework are backwards compatible, so any project that needs to reference EF4 should still work with code that needs 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mvc 2 with EF v1 with .net framework 3.5